# Sql Xquery How to Replace text in Update Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, xquery-sql, xquery-update

Table is named as `MasterTable`

Columns

`ID` type `BIGINT`,

`Name` type `VARCHAR(200)` (stores `xml` type data for some reasons)

`Name` contains data structured as

`<en-US>SomeEnglishText</en-US><it-IT>SomeItalicText</it-IT>`

When I need to `Update` the `Master` Table then at that time I Need to cast the `Varchar` to `xml` then conditionally **update / replace** the `value` part of particular tag i.e either `en-US / it-IT`.

Also there are chances that **No data/tags** are there in `Name` column so I think at the time of Inserting data it would `Insert` empty tag elements in the table like `<en-US></en-US><it-IT></it-IT>`, so the `update` query **must** handle **empty value** in tag elements namely `en-US/it-IT`.

I am trying to do it like following update query.

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(200)

SET @Str = 'Test Text'

UPDATE [MasterTable]
SET [Name] = cast([MasterTable].[Name] as xml).modify('replace value of (en-US/text())[1] with sql:variable("@Str")')
WHERE [ID]=18
```

I getting following error when running the query

> Illegal use of xml data type method 'modify'. A non-mutator method is expected in this context.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can not assign from a xml.modify. Modify works on the variable/column directly. You can also not use modify on a cast.

You can extract the name to a xml variable, modify the xml and then put it back to the table.

```
declare @str varchar(200) = 'Test'
declare @xml xml

select @xml = cast(Name as xml)
from MasterTable
where ID = 18

set @xml.modify('replace value of (en-US/text())[1] with sql:variable("@Str")')

update MasterTable
set Name = cast(@xml as varchar(200))
where ID = 18
```

If you need this to work over more than one row at a time you can use a table variable with columns `id` and `name` where data type for name is `xml` instead of the `@xml` variable.

```
declare @str varchar(200) = 'Test Text'
declare @T table (ID int, Name xml)

insert into @T
select ID, cast(Name as xml)
from MasterTable
where Name is not null

update @T
set Name.modify('replace value of (en-US/text())[1] with sql:variable("@Str")')

update MasterTable
set Name = cast(T.Name as varchar(200))
from @T as T
where MasterTable.ID = T.ID
```

Comment: I had changed this `declare @str varchar(200) = 'Test'` to  `declare @str varchar(200) 
set @str = 'Test'` and it worked.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you tell that how to do if the previous code was `COALESCE(@Name, Name)` and now I want to changed it as `UPDATE MasterTable
set Name = Name.modify('replace value of (en-US/text())[1] with sql:variable("@Str")')

where ID = 18` like-wise
i.e handle NULLs in @Str

Comment: Also as the `Name` column is `VARCHAR(200)` so I am facing problem of directly calling `modify` on it

Comment: @Harsh: You can not call modify directly on a varchar column. You need to move it to a xml column (or variable) to use modify as in the code in my answer.

Comment: So here as we need to first take the values in separate `@xml` variable so if We have multi columns as `Name` on which we want to update then we would need to declare multiple `@xml` variables to update multiple language columns, this is not good I think...

Comment: @Harsh: You can use a table variable with multiple xml columns.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson can you edit the question for multiple rows because I am not able to get how to do that.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson You are much helpful Huge Thank to you :D

Comment: You can also use sql:column to use value from other column. Example: UPDATE @TXML
    SET Config.modify('replace value of (/UNIT_CONFIG/CONTRACTOR/text())[1] with sql:column("NewContractorId")')